# Using a custom formatter in a DataGridView

Tags: winforms, datagridview, string-formatting, iformatprovider

So, maybe this is a bad design; I don't know. But say I have a `DataTable` with a column that holds `int` values; these values are in fact meant to represent some `enum` type that I have in my project.

What I'd like to do is have a `DataGridView` bound to this table and have the column display the name of the `enum` rather than the integer value "0" or "1" or whatever.

One option I considered was to do the whole normalization thing: add a table in the `DataSet` with the `enum` names in it, keyed on the `enum` values, and have my first table hold a reference to *this* table.

But this is an `enum`-specific idea. I would like to know if, in general, I can write my own `IFormatProvider` and `ICustomFormatter` implementation* for a given type and use that formatter to control how values are displayed in a given column of a `DataGridView` control (or really in *any* control, for that matter).

<sub>*This is just how I suspect it would be done, if what I'm asking is possible at all. I'm not really dead-set on using these interfaces at all.</sub>

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can indeed implement a custom `ICustomFormatter`, but due to some brokenness on the part of the `DataGridView`, you need to actually tell it how to apply your formatter.

First set `column.DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider` to an instance of your custom formatting class. Then, handle the `CellFormatting` event:

```
void dataGridView_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e) {
    if (e.CellStyle.FormatProvider is ICustomFormatter) {
        e.Value = (e.CellStyle.FormatProvider.GetFormat(typeof(ICustomFormatter)) as ICustomFormatter).Format(e.CellStyle.Format, e.Value, e.CellStyle.FormatProvider);
        e.FormattingApplied = true;
    }
}
```

The formatter class would look something like this:

```
public class MyEnumFormatter : IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter {

    public object GetFormat(Type formatType) {
        if (formatType == typeof(ICustomFormatter))
            return this;
        else
            return null;
    }

    public string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider) {
        return ((NameOfEnumType)Convert.ToInt32(arg)).ToString();
    }

}
```