# C# full hour format

Tags: c#, datetime, formatting

I have a sample date

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Parse("2011-01-01 00:00:00");
DateTime endDate = DateTime.Parse("2011-01-03 01:01:03");
```

How can I get it to Elapsed time of 49:01:03? I can't get any string format including days.

Currently I want to use that on DataGridView's Columns.

Below is the sample code of it:

```
private void dataGridView1_ColumnAdded(object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
{
    e.Column.CellTemplate.Style.FormatProvider = new DayToHour();
    //e.Column.CellTemplate.Style.Format = "";
}
```

But I can't get it work :(.

Note: I don't have any problem on subtracting the date and time. I'm asking about the format.

> Closed: Just used wrapper class inheriting from IFormatProvider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there might no such format available so you will have to get the value on these lines

```
TimeSpan diff = endDate - startDate;
String.Format("{0:00}hr {1:00}mn {2:00}sec",
                     Math.Truncate(diff.TotalHours),diff.Minutes,diff.Seconds);
```

Also have a look at this [Custom Format provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551575/using-a-custom-formatter-in-a-datagridview)

Answer (score 3):

Use the TimeSpan class:

```
TimeSpan ts = endDate - startDate;
```

Then you got in TimeSpan class all the information you need. I am assuming formatting is not the issue.

Comment: Next time when you post code, select the code and press the { } Code Sample icon or alternatively press `Ctrl + K` to format it nicely :)

Answer (score 0):

```
TimeSpan tp = endDate.Subtract(startDate);
string myString = tp.ToString("c");
```

`myString` should contain the elapsed time. Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx) for other timespan formats.

Comment: If he wants total hours rather than days, hours etc, there is no built-in TimeSpan format string for it.

Comment: Uhm, he wrote `I can't get any string format including days.`, maybe I understood it wrong

Comment: He specified the output he wanted: "How can I get it to Elapsed time of 49:01:03?" - note that it has total hours at the start without any day information. Not sure why he then goes on to talk about "including days". Just a bad specification I think. ;)

Comment: @MatthewWatson why did you think it's a bad specification?

Comment: Because the example format "49:01:03" shows total hours, not days, but your textual specification says "including days" which contradicts the example format. I think you meant to say "including total hours" rather than "including days".

Comment: @MatthewWatson If you say total hours you also include the minutes and seconds which is I'm trying to avoid. I just want the "day and hour" for "HH", minutes for "mm" and seconds for "ss"

Comment: The code sample I provided produces "49:01:03" - isn't that what you wanted? If not, then you should adjust your specification so that it states what you actually want. When I'm saying "total hours" I mean simply the total number of hours (excluding minutes and seconds) rather than a value between 0 and 23.

Comment: I though he had gone up that far to get the 49:01:03, and he wanted it including days (I still read it and think that's the question)... but then again English is not my native language, so I might have misunderstood. Sorry if I did.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
using System;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DateTime startDate = DateTime.Parse("2011-01-01 00:00:00");
            DateTime endDate = DateTime.Parse("2011-01-03 01:01:03");

            TimeSpan elapsed = endDate - startDate;

            string result = string.Format("{0:d2}:{1:d2}:{2:d2}", elapsed.Days*24 + elapsed.Hours, elapsed.Minutes, elapsed.Seconds);

            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not too sure how you will get that displayed in the control. You might need to write a wrapper class that implements a ToString() that does the right thing, and pass that in.