# Change number group separator in numeric columns of DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, cell-formatting

I want to format cells that are numeric in this way `1 231 241.45`. I've tried `N2` format option:

```
datagridview1.Columns["col1"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2";
```

But `N2` format puts comma instead of space. I want space as number group separator. 
Is it possible to change number group separator?

Comment: _It is possible?_ Did you tried anything? Show your effort! Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's help me a lot! I think i have to use format.ToString("") but not know what to put inside...

Comment: Really? =) BTW, it wasn't an answer! It was a [*comment*](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: You should check if datagrid had any `FormatProvider` option maybe then you can roll your own custom format something like its [shown here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551575/using-a-custom-formatter-in-a-datagridview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the number group separator in `DataGridView` you can create a specific culture and then set its `NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator` to new value, then set `DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider` of the `DataGridView` to the modified culture:

```
var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB");
culture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = " ";
dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = culture;
dataGridView1.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2";
```

Comment: Because he is **`Most Valuable Professional`** :D

Answer (score 4):

I managed to make it work with the following code:

```
string NRFormat="### ### ##0.00"
datagridview1.Columns["col1"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = NRFormat;
datagridview1.Columns["col2"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = NRFormat;
```

It's not very elegant, but it's working.

Comment: While it works for numbers like `123456789.12345` but it doesn't work for larger numbers like `123456789000.12345`.

Answer (score 2):

Refer this link for cellstyle formatting>>

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

```
this.dgv_PreviewGrid.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "D4";
```

D is for integers.

Comment: This is not working. D is for decimals. I get error for each cell formatting option.

Answer (score 0):

you may try this one.

```
//1000001 convert to 1 000 001.00
datagridview1.Columns["col1"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "### ### ##0.00";

//1000 convert to 1 000.00
datagridview1.Columns["col2"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "### ### ##0.00";
```

Answer (score 0):

In the data grid `CellFormatting` event do the following:

```
private void dg_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (cell.Value is decimal)
    {
        e.CellStyle.Format = "0.##";
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't compile.